# Produce all row groups having a SUM between two values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table as below(products)

```
id  name      quality  weight
1   Demir-1   ST-1     10
2   Demir-2   ST-2      7
3   Demir-3   ST-1     20
4   Demir-2   ST-3      8
5   Demir-1   ST-3      6
6   Demir-4   ST-2     10
7   Demir-2   ST-2     12
8   Demir-1   ST-1     15
9   Demir-1   ST-3     10
10  Demir-3   ST-3      5
11  Demir-2   ST-2      5
```

Now if a user wants to get list of products which sum of weight will between 20 and 25 and name='Result-2' then the result should be as below. All combination must be shown where sum of weight between 20 and 25.

```
 id name      quality  weight    
  4 Demir-2   ST-3      8   
  7 Demir-2   ST-2     12   
 11 Demir-2  ST-2       5
------------------------------
  2 Demir-2   ST-2      7
  4 Demir-2   ST-3      8
 11 Demir-2   ST-2      5
------------------------------ 
------------------------------ 
  1 Demir-1   ST-1     10
  8 Demir-1   ST-1     15
```

You can see that the sum(weight) is 25.

Comment: Based on your sample, is it must all name the same in that combination  or you just need sum of weight between 20 and 25?

Comment: I am still not clear. Even id  = 1 and id  = 8 (name: Demir-1 ) will give you 25. So, how come your final output will comprise of a combination of id 4,7 and 11?..Please explain

Comment: Could you please update your final result set? Also should the combination will reside only in the same "Name" group or it can span e.g. Id 3 and 11 ...will this be a valid combination?

Comment: yes you are right final i updated the fimnal result. it must include also wher id =1 and i=8

Comment: Could you please update the expected result and the format you want it is your query window.Please ..it will help us to understand the requirement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: lets make it simple. get result where name is qeual to 'Demir - 2'.

Comment: 5 Demir-1 ST-3 6 <br>
8 Demir-1 ST-1 15 why this row is not there in the OP

Comment: yes it must be there. but i did't add all comibations. but i have said that in my result must include all of combinations

Comment: This sounds a lot like the 'knapsack problem', except that you want all possible combinations, not just the best one.

Comment: Hi, the total record will be 10..please confirm my answer. I made my own format..please check and let me know about the combinations.We can decide upon the final format later.First check the output and response me asap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @tblProducts TABLE(Id INT IDENTITY, ProductName varchar(50),Quality varchar(50), ProductWeight int)
INSERT INTO @tblProducts SELECT 'Demir-1','ST-1',10
INSERT INTO @tblProducts SELECT 'Demir-2','ST-2',7
INSERT INTO @tblProducts SELECT 'Demir-3','ST-1',20
INSERT INTO @tblProducts SELECT 'Demir-2','ST-3',8
INSERT INTO @tblProducts SELECT  'Demir-1','ST-3',6
INSERT INTO @tblProducts SELECT  'Demir-4','ST-2',10
INSERT INTO @tblProducts SELECT 'Demir-2','ST-2' ,12
INSERT INTO @tblProducts SELECT  'Demir-1','ST-1',15
INSERT INTO @tblProducts SELECT  'Demir-1','ST-3',10
INSERT INTO @tblProducts SELECT 'Demir-3','ST-3' ,5
INSERT INTO @tblProducts SELECT 'Demir-2' ,'ST-2 ',5

 ;WITH Cte (Id,ProductQuality,ProductIds,ProductNames,ProductQualities,ProductTotalWeight,ProductWeights,ProductName1,ProductName2) AS
(
    SELECT  Id
            ,Quality            
            , ',' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(MAX))  
            ,',' + CAST(ProductName AS VARCHAR(MAX))
            ,',' + CAST(Quality AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
            ,ProductWeight
            , ',' + CAST(ProductWeight AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
            ,ProductName
            ,CAST(ProductName AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM @tblProducts
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.Id
            , p.Quality            
            ,c.ProductIds + ',' +  CAST(p.Id AS VARCHAR(MAX))
            ,c.ProductNames + ',' +  CAST(p.ProductName AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
             ,c.ProductQualities + ',' + CAST(p.Quality AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
             ,c.ProductTotalWeight + p.ProductWeight          
            ,c.ProductWeights + ',' + CAST(p.ProductWeight AS VARCHAR(MAX))
            ,p.ProductName
            ,c.ProductName2
    FROM @tblProducts AS p JOIN Cte c ON p.Id < c.Id
    WHERE  p.ProductName = c.ProductName2
    )
SELECT 
        ProductIds = STUFF(ProductIds,1,1,'')
        ,ProductNames = STUFF(ProductNames,1,1,'')
        ,ProductQualities = STUFF(ProductQualities,1,1,'')
        ,ProductTotalWeight
        ,ProductWeights = STUFF(ProductWeights,1,1,'')
FROM CTE 
WHERE ProductTotalWeight BETWEEN 20 AND 25
```

**Result**

```
ProductIds  ProductNames             ProductQualities   ProductTotalWeight  ProductWeights
3           Demir-3                 ST-1                20                  20
11,7,2      Demir-2,Demir-2,Demir-2 ST-2 ,ST-2,ST-2     24                  5,12,7
11,7,4      Demir-2,Demir-2,Demir-2 ST-2 ,ST-2,ST-3     25                  5,12,8
11,4,2      Demir-2,Demir-2,Demir-2 ST-2 ,ST-3,ST-2     20                  5,8,7
10,3        Demir-3,Demir-3         ST-3,ST-1           25                  5,20
9,1         Demir-1,Demir-1         ST-3,ST-1           20                 10,10
9,8         Demir-1,Demir-1         ST-3,ST-1           25                 10,15
8,1         Demir-1,Demir-1         ST-1,ST-1           25                 15,10
8,5         Demir-1,Demir-1         ST-1,ST-3           21                  15,6
7,4         Demir-2,Demir-2         ST-2,ST-3           20                  12,8
```

Comment: i am sure that @Nat's answer is very usefull in my sutiation. and it gives result as i want. your one gives different result. +1 but it is for another situation. and good algorithm

Comment: How can you say that..I am getting the correct combination and the totalProduct weight for every ProductName group.Let me know in case case it differed. I check the result. However, waiting for ur response.

Comment: i see you have updated your Result. on really i run @Nats script. and it gave me what i needed. and then looked to you response but did not run your script. i saw that result is different what i need

Comment: That is what I am asking..because if u look into the ProductWeights and then sum up, it is coming in the range.Kindly let me know ur concern

Comment: really what i need) thanks. Look in @Nat's script it does not show  first row of your result (3  Demir-3  ST-1  20   20)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, SQL is not the correct coding engine for coming up with all combinations from a table with a given calculation, as SQL code I hacked together shows.

Normally I would recommend this is coded in a procedural language given it's nature. 
Note also that the solution here, with larger input data sets can quickly exhaust SQL's recursion limit. The number of possible products can also grow to sufficently large numbers that it will run very slowly.

```
drop table products
drop table #MinW
drop table #Products
go
create table products
(
id  int,
name  varchar(20),  
quality varchar(20),
[weight] int
) 
go
insert into products
select
1,   'Demir-1',   'ST-1',     10 
union
select 2,   'Demir-2',   'ST-2',      7 
union
select 3,   'Demir-3',   'ST-1',     20 
union
select 4,   'Demir-2',   'ST-3',      8 
union
select 5,   'Demir-1',   'ST-3',      6 
union
select 6,   'Demir-4',   'ST-2',     10 
union
select 7,   'Demir-2',   'ST-2',     12 
union
select 8,   'Demir-1',   'ST-1',     15 
union
select 9,   'Demir-1',   'ST-3',     10 
union
select 10,  'Demir-3',   'ST-3',      5 
union
select 11,  'Demir-2',   'ST-2',      5 
go
select 
p.id, p.name, p.quality, p.weight
into #MinW
from products p
inner join
(
select name,min(weight) as weight
from products group by name having min(weight) < 25
) as minW
on p.name = minW.name and p.weight = minW.weight

go
with weightProducts (id, name, [weight],history)
as
( 
select id, name,[weight],convert(varchar(1024),'"'+convert(varchar(10),id)+'",') from #minW
union all
select products.id, products.name,products.[weight] + weightProducts.[weight],convert(varchar(1024),weightProducts.history+'"'+convert(varchar(10),products.id)+'",') from products, weightProducts where products.name = weightproducts.name and  charindex('"'+convert(varchar(10),products.id)+'",',weightProducts.history)<=0 and (products.weight + weightProducts.weight) < 25
)
-- Statement using the CTE
select *
into #Products
from weightProducts
where weight between 20 and 25

go

select 
p1.history,
p2.id,
p2.quality,
p2.weight,
p1.weight as totalWeight
from #Products p1
inner join
products p2 on p1.name = p2.name and charindex('"'+convert(varchar(10),p2.id)+'",',p1.history)>0
order by 
p1.history,
p2.id
```

Comment: where is result :   3 Demir-3 ST-1 20 20

Comment: @Nat , "11","2","7" and "11","7","2" is duplicated. Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE name IN (
 SELECT name FROM tablename 
 GROUP BY name
 HAVING SUM(weight) BETWEEN 20 AND 25)
```

Comment: no it is not result as i want. @Niladri Biswas understood my question. and i updated my result set look plz

Comment: Not what the asked asked for.

Comment: @DanDascalescu OP edited the question multiple times as evident from revision history. I answered the question based on whatever information was available from the original post. If the question is clarified or changed later then obviously the answer may not be valid.

Answer (score 0):

How about this query:

```
select id, name, quality, weight from PRODUCTS
group by id, name, quality, weight
having sum(weight) between 20 and 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE name IN (
              SELECT name FROM products
              GROUP BY name
              HAVING SUM(weight) BETWEEN 20 AND 25)
```